# Yii2 migration exception with no driver, but modules has installed

Tags: php, yii2

**EDIT:** The whole issue is because of my fault.

I am running php from docker, and I tried to run migration creation on my localhost, not in the container.

---

I am facing with a strange problem. Yes, I know there are thousands of thread about this topic, but everywhere is just a missing library causes this.

My website works well, authentication came  from database, so the database configuration is right.

The funny thin is  that I have installed all the necessary modules. From `php -m` I've got:

```
...
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
...
```

so mysqli, mysqlnd, PDO and pdo_mysql is there.

How can I fix this?

Here is my stack trace:

Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

```
in /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:649

Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

in /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:723

Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(723): PDO->__construct()
#1 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(638): yii\db\Connection->createPdoInstance()
#2 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(1063): yii\db\Connection->open()
#3 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(1050): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
#4 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(261): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
#5 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1163): yii\db\Command->prepare()
#6 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(410): yii\db\Command->queryInternal()
#7 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(319): yii\db\Command->queryAll()
#8 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(125): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findColumns()
#9 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(758): yii\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema()
#10 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(194): yii\db\Schema->getTableMetadata()
#11 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(369): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema()
#12 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(657): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigrationNameLimit()
#13 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionCreate()
#14 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#15 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#16 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(184): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#17 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\console\Controller->runAction()
#18 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(181): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#19 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(148): yii\console\Application->runAction()
#20 /srv/www/mito/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\console\Application->handleRequest()
#21 /srv/www/mito/app/yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Try checking the `console.php` config. Old versions of yii2 basic app template didn't have common DB config file for web/console application. If your app is based on them it might still have separate db configuration.

Comment: I have the latest yii2, I've just installed it with composer about one week ago. In the `console.php` in the config the `$db` is came from the `db.php`, I've checked and dumped, there are the right values.